# Composer plugins disabled in Docker: Set COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=1 to enable plugins

Tags: reactjs, laravel, docker-compose, dockerfile, composer-php

I'm trying to set up my React + Laravel application with Docker, but I'm encountering an issue while running the `composer install` command inside the Docker container.

When I run `docker-compose up -d --build`, the build fails at the `composer install` step with the following error:

"[backend 8/9] RUN composer install --no-interaction --no-scripts --no-plugins:
#0 0.537 Composer plugins have been disabled for safety in this non-interactive session. Set COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=1 if you want to allow plugins to run as root/super user."

I have tried adding the `COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=1` environment variable in various places, including in the Dockerfile, the docker-compose.yaml file, and even as a command-line argument when running `docker-compose up`. However, I still encounter the same error.

Here is an example of my docker-compose.yaml file:

```
version: '3'
services:
backend:
build:
context: .
dockerfile: Dockerfile
environment:
- COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=1
volumes:
- .:/app
# other service configuration...
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Is this a Docker problem, a Composer problem, a Laravel problem, or a React problem?

Comment: It's a dependency manager for PHP problem:  Composer (https://getcomposer.org). Because we generally run Docker  as root (a Docker problem), Composer (the PHP manager) throw an error by default, as it can't be executed as root.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to use superuser for composer, you have to include

```
ENV COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=1
```

Before the composer install command in your Dockerfile.

However, a safer option is to use a non-root user such as `USER www-data` in your Dockerfile instead of superuser.

Comment: Please read the question once more: the OP tried to set this in different places already, but did not succeed

Comment: @NicoHaase read my comment again. I was facing the same situation and this worked for me. also OP tried `COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=1` but I'm stating a different command ie `ENV COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=1`.

Comment: How does `ENV COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=1` differ from setting an environment variable using the `docker-compose.yml`?

Comment: Feel free to add all clarification to your answer by editing it. The OP also wrote that he included the setting in the Dockerfile, and that this did not work. As the OP hasn't shared the current state of the Dockerfile, it's impossible for others to reproduce the problem or check whether your solution really works

Answer (score -3):

You have to change the php version in the backend Dockerfile to a newer version

```
FROM php:8.2
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. The error message does not indicate that the PHP version is relevant after all